# How to synchronize db sqlite of android with a rest service made with nodejs?

Tags: sqlite, synchronization, android-studio-3.0

I'm making an Android application that was designed to receive data from families in a certain place. This place does not have Internet connections, so I use SQLite. How can I synchronize the data stored in SQLite with a web service made with nodejs?

I was recommended to use Retrofit, but I really do not know if it is necessary since I see examples where they occupy HTTPClient

Answer (score 0):

I would give Realm.io a look. They have a (paid) platform with synchronization built-in between their Realm mobile database and their Realm Object Server.

There aren't any free services/platforms that handle synchronization. You will have to write your own logic if paid options are not acceptable. It is hard to do, it is hard to test, and it is really easy to screw up your data.